# Polymer dom repeat index to a variable

Tags: java, json, polymer, polymer-1.0

So I have this dom repeat where all lessons get displayed of the class of an user which I get from a json.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lessen}}">
    <div><paper-button id="{{index}}" on-click="toggleDialog">{{index}} - {{item.lessen}}</paper-button></div>
</template>
```

Is there a way I can get the value of '{{index}}' to send to my backend via iron-ajax? I got this function:

```
sendAfmelding: function() {
      console.log("Afmelden van les met user="+this.username);
      if (this.rol == "student") {
        console.log("indexnummer = "+this.$.index);
        this.$.ajax2.contentType="application/json";
        this.$.ajax2.body={
          "username":this.username,
          "lesIndex":this.$.index    // <-- needs to change
        };
        this.$.ajax2.generateRequest();
      }
    }
```

I got everything correctly set up. Username get's send and everything, the only thing I still need is that index value. For example, if I put

```
"lesIndex":"1"
```

in my function my code will do exacly what I want but ofcourse I want the user to select the lesson himself.

I hope my question is a bit clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
id$="{{index}}"
```

is what you want to get attribute binding instead of property binding.

See for example the 2nd-last paragraph before https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind

Answer (score 2):

The `index` is exposed on the item's click event, you can access it inside `toggleDialog`:

```
toggleDialog: function (event) {
    var index = event.model.index;
    sendAfmelding(index); // I assumed you were calling this somewhere in here
}
```

And then ofcourse add the parameter to the `sendAfmelding` function:

```
sendAfmelding: function (index) {
    console.log("Afmelden van les met user=" + this.username);
    if (this.rol == "student") {
        console.log("indexnummer = " + index);
        this.$.ajax2.contentType = "application/json";
        this.$.ajax2.body = {
            "username": this.username,
            "lesIndex": index
        };
        this.$.ajax2.generateRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: event.model.index . That is exactly what I was looking for . Thanks